# Ionic Build Error: :mergeDebugAssets Could not merge source set folders

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to run "ionic build android", the build process runs half the way and shows error after this line:

```
:mergeDebugAssets
Could not merge source set folders:
```

I have tried all the available answers in last 24 hrs but nothing worked, I am started to get this error after updating JDK to latest version,

I have tried these so far.
Updated Android SDK, removed Android platform and added it back, updated android platform to  android@6.2.2, removed all the dev dependencies form package.json file tried to replace tools folder from Android SDK, but nothing worked.
My ionic info
Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.10 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.11.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Below is the big error log,

```
add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/amitabhs/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home

:wrapper




BUILD SUCCESSFUL


Total time: 1.744 secs

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

        at build_7w3ckihviy9j3ktiflnuopmyu.run(/Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/build.gradle:138)

The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.


Incremental Java compilation is an incubating feature.


The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.


:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE

:checkDebugManifest


:preReleaseBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies

:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl


:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint


:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders


:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders


:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles


:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript


:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues


:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources


:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources


:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig


:CordovaLib:processDebugResources


:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources

:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard


:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac


:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug


:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug


:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders


:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug


:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug


:CordovaLib:bundleDebug


:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl


:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders


:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders


:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets


:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets


:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles


:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript


:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues


:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources


:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest


:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig


:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources

:CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease


:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease


:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders


:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease


:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease


:CordovaLib:bundleRelease


:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132340Library


:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library


:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase980Library


:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement980Library


:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm980Library


:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid980Library


:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks980Library


:prepareMeLeolinShortcutBadger114Library


:prepareOrgApacheCordovaCordovaLib622DebugLibrary


:prepareDebugDependencies


:compileDebugAidl


:compileDebugRenderscript


:generateDebugBuildConfig


:generateDebugResValues


:generateDebugResources

:mergeDebugResources

:processDebugManifest


:processDebugResources


:generateDebugSources


:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard


:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:compileDebugNdk

UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources


:mergeDebugShaders


:compileDebugShaders


:generateDebugAssets


:mergeDebugAssets
Could not merge source set folders:





 * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
    > [www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js  [www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js    [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js    [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/underscore/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/underscore/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar        [www/lib/underscore/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/underscore/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar    [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar    [www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/fingerprintjs2/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/fingerprintjs2/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js      [www/lib/fingerprintjs2/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/fingerprintjs2/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js        [www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/fingerprintjs2/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/fingerprintjs2/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js      [www/lib/fingerprintjs2/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/fingerprintjs2/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js  [www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/angularjs-slider/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/underscore/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/underscore/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js      [www/lib/underscore/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/underscore/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/log4js/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/asse
    ts/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/log4js/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js   [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/log4js/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/log4js/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js        [www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar  [www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ngCordova/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar-pack/test/fixtures/packed.tar.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/underscore/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/underscore/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js      [www/lib/underscore/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/underscore/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/log4js/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/log4js/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js  [www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/log4js/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ion-autocomplete/node_modules/log4js/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ionic-ratings/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic-ratings/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js        [www/lib/ionic-ratings/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic-ratings/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
      [www/lib/ionic-ratings/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic-ratings/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js        [www/lib/ionic-ratings/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] /Users/amitabhs/Projects/Kudaap/KudaapCourts/Mobile/KudappIonic_Courts/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic-ratings/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Full error log is very big please check [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BHJ8vtKhO6dnfVM5qXxUBtjAnQSX2NyJp0GdeVwtuMQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check your splash and icon. Make sure they are not corrupted.

Comment: I have checked, also used this command ionic resources to rebuild assets, but still not working.

Comment: Replace them with default ionic's icon and splash, then `run ionic resources `

Comment: Make sure that everything got updated inside `resources\android`

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa just tried your solution, it's not working, I think the problem is with node module libraries.

Comment: create a fresh app and try to build.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete the semver directory.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I deleted all instances of semver.min.js.gz and semver.browser.js.gz from the project.